# Excel doesn't sum up numbers with 16 digit

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I was doing random calculation and I observed a fatal error in Excel

can you test it

B2 = 1000000000000000
C2= B2 + 8   ==> excel displays 1000000000000000
D2= C2-B2    ==> excel displays 0

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

EXCEL stores and performs calculations with 15 significant digits precision. Therefore, it will not be possible to enter a 20-digit number without EXCEL automatically rounding it to the nearest 100,000,000. We use a text format to display such numbers.
The fact that calculations in EXCEL are performed with an accuracy of 15 significant digits is manifested, for example, when writing a whole twenty-digit number to a cell. The exponential format will be applied to the number.
It is impossible to increase the accuracy of calculations in EXCEL. However, if numbers are not expected to participate in mathematical operations, then a text format can be used to store them. This solution is suitable, for example, for storing bank account numbers.
When calculating such values, difficulties can arise.

If you need to count the number of cells containing the desired numbers in a given format, use the `COUNTIF` function (Counts the number of cells in a range that match one user-specified criterion.)
Use the formula (for example)

`=COUNTIF(A7:A14;"*"&C9)`,

where `A7-A14` is the cell search range,

`C9` is the user's criterion (the required number)